# No suitable driver found for SQL Server in Netbeans 7

Tags: sql-server, classpath, netbeans-7

I use SQL Server 2005 with the driver `sqlsgbd4` and I want to connect to a database from NetBeans 7.3.

I have the driver jar in the `CLASSPATH`, and this exception is still thrown after running my program.

Can you help?

Comment: You should avoid shouting and just state the question with an appropriate title and tags.

Comment: What is `sqlsgbd4`? Did you mean `sqljdbc4`? And there are [dozens of questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+server+no+suitable+driver+found) already on this site about that error, did you review them?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on project and choose properties. Go Library i hope this help you..